# Multiple tabs navigation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can I design section like given in image using bootstrap tabs?
The number of tabs are dynamic. I just wants navigation functionality.
I have tried using bootstrap tabs but it does not provide navigation and shows 
all tabs at a time.
How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: what you tried? show some codes ..

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use jQuery to detect when the tabs are too wide for the container, and the show prev/next arrows accordingly...

[Show arrows for overflowing tabs](http://bootply.com/128029)

Another option is to place the overflowing tabs into a dropdown menu like this..

[Place overflowing tabs in dropdown menu](http://bootply.com/124888)

Comment: Getting "500 Server Error" for first link

Comment: Thanks. I will try to implement this

Comment: It fails, when their are even more tabs eg.100. I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Do you really want 100 tabs? That sounds like a poor UI decision. Anyway you may need to tweak the code to get it to work.

Comment: I am not setting these tabs static. Providing UI for user to add multiple news heading. And then show separate tab for each news heading. SO I can't say how many heading users will add!